# Trying to create a new linked server in SSMS: Can't find table 0

Tags: sql-server-2008

All of my Linked Servers stopped working and I have no idea why.\

When I try to create a new linked server in SSMS I get the following error:

> Can't find table

Suggestions?

I'm on 2008 R2.

Update: I was able to connect to SQL, or least it looks liked I was connected in the Object Explorer, but when I try to open a Query Window:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

I seem to have no problem signing onto the domain when rebooting my PC..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bizarre. Rebooting didn't help, but restating the SQL ServerService seemed to corerct the issue.

Update:

Now I am getting

OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "servername" returned message "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.".

Final Update:

Total corruption, error message after error message within SSMS whenever I touch teh Link Server functionality.

Solution: Delete ALL the linked servers and re add. This stabalized everything.

Update:

Something about hitting a DB2 linked serevr that just trashes my whole SQL environment.It happened when I recreated the DB2 linked server.